# Define a column as nullable in System.Data.DataTable

Tags: c#, types, datatable, nullable

I need to define a `System.Data.DataTable` in C# VS2013; in one column, it may be int or null.

But I got:

> DataSet does not support System.Nullable<>.

For the definition:

```
public DataTable myDataTable
myDataTable = new DataTable("myName");
myDataTable.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(Int32)); 
myDataTable.Columns.Add("value1", typeof(Int32?)); // run time error 
myDataTable.Columns.Add("value2", typeof(Int32?));
```

Any ideas? Work around?

After making the column nullable,

```
DataColumn dc = myDataTable.Columns.Add("value1", typeof(Int32));
dc.AllowDBNull = true;
```

When I queried it, I got

> Sequence contains no elements.

Please see the UPDATE.

**UPDATE**

```
int? result = (from r in myDataTable.AsEnumerable()
               where r.Field<Int32>("ID") == givenID
                   && r.Field<Int32?>("value1") == givenValue1
               select r.Field<Int32>("value2")).First();
```

Comment: You already got an answer explaining how to solve this, but I'd like to explain *why* it's like this: Nullable data types were added in .NET Framework 2.0, but DataTable has been with us since (at least) .NET Framework 1.1.

Answer (score 21):

It is a property of the DataColumn

```
public DataTable myDataTable
myDataTable = new DataTable("myName");
myDataTable.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(Int32)); 
DataColumn dc = myDataTable.Columns.Add("value1", typeof(Int32)); 
dc.AllowDBNull = true;
```

[MSDN about AllowDBNull](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.allowdbnull(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thanks, it works, But when I queried it, I got "Sequence contains no elements". Please see the UPDATE.

Comment: This is a different problem. If the result of the query has no match then you cannot use First because exactly 'sequence contains no elements'. Instead use FirstOrDefault

Answer (score 9):

TRY

```
  public DataTable myDataTable
  myDataTable = new DataTable("myName");
  myDataTable.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(Int32)); 
  myDataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn { ColumnName = "VALUE1", DataType = typeof(int), AllowDBNull = true });
  myDataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn { ColumnName = "VALUE2", DataType = typeof(int), AllowDBNull = true });
```

this will make value columns nullable

and at time of insert

```
DataRow dr = myDataTable.NewRow();
dr["VALUE1"] = object.value1==null? (object)DBNull.Value : object.value1;
```

This will do what is required

Answer (score 1):

or to make it even shorter one line:

```
table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("ID", typeof(Int32)) { AllowDBNull = true });
```

and:

```
row["ID"] = (object) nullableId ?? DBNull.Value;
```