# Merging 2 DataTables gives "NullReferenceException", even though both DataTables are not null

Tags: c#

I have 2 DataTabables, which I want to merge.

Here is a snippet of code for creating 1st DataTable:

```
            using (DataTable dt = admission.ExecuteQuery(txtID.Text))
            {
                if (dt.Rows.Count < 1)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Position nicht vorhanden");
                    return;
                }

                updateGui(dt);
                SendKeys.Send("{TAB}");
            }
```

And here is the merging:

```
 private void updateGui(DataTable dt)
    {

        DataTable inventTable = dataSet1.Mytable;

        inventTable.Clear();
        inventTable.Merge(dt);
        inventTable.Rows[0].SetAdded();
```

Merging those 2 tables gives NullReferenceException(object reference not set to an instance of an object). I checked with debugger, none of the tables are "null", column names and types are the same and "dt" table has the right data.

EDIT 1:
Here is a detailed error:

```
    System.NullReferenceException
  HResult=0x80004003
  Message=The object reference was not set to an object instance.
  Source=System.Data
  StackTrace:
   at System.Data.Merger.MergeSchema(DataTable table)
   at System.Data.Merger.MergeTableData(DataTable src)
   at System.Data.Merger.MergeTable(DataTable src)
   at System.Data.DataTable.Merge(DataTable table, Boolean preserveChanges, MissingSchemaAction missingSchemaAction)
   at System.Data.DataTable.Merge(DataTable table)
   at InventurAufnahmePrototyp.MainForm.updateDbInfo(DataTable dt) in <path>/MainForm.cs:line 1033
   at InventurAufnahmePrototyp.MainForm.txtID_KeyDown(Object sender, KeyEventArgs e) in <path>/MainForm.cs:line 359
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ProcessKeyEventArgs(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ProcessKeyMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmKeyChar(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.TextBoxBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.TextBox.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
   at InventurAufnahmePrototyp.Program.Main() in <path>/Program.cs:line 19
```

Some clarifications:
Program.cs:19 just launches the window (mainForm.cs file)
MainForm.cs:359 calls updateGui function

Comment: do both datatables allow null equally on columns? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40953738/define-a-column-as-nullable-in-system-data-datatable

Comment: Post the full exception text. Right now we can't tell which line throws

Comment: @RandRandom I double checked "dt" table has some does not allow some columns to be null, but "inventTable" allows them to be null. So this should not be a problem.

Comment: „should not“ isn’t I tested and am 100% sure it’s not a problem

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos what I get is "An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in System.Data.dll" and Debugger in VS pointing to line "inventTable.Merge(dt);". Is there a way to see a more detailed message or is this what you meant?

Comment: in call stack window you can right click and enable show external code - in tools -> options -> debugging you can disable Just my code

Comment: That's not the exception text, just the message. Post the entire string returned by `Exception.ToString()` or by clicking on `Copy Details` in the exception popup and add it to the question itself. This includes the entire call stack and any inner exceptions. This could point to the internal method that caused the error

Comment: @RandRandom correct me if I am wrong, but "dt" table is being merged into "inventTable", so basically, whatever values (null or not null) "dt" table has, "inventTable" will accept them (since it allows null for all columns. that "dt" table has).

Comment: I would simply test it, writing a foreach loop and setting allownull on all columns to test it seems easy

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos added full error message in the question

Comment: @RandRandom I've tested setting AllowDBNull to "true" on "dt" table, didn't work, had exactly the same error message. Then I set AllowDBNull to "true" on both tables, still same error

And I checked "Just my code" setting, it is "off".

Comment: stacktrace seems to indicate an issue with the schemas of the datatables - since I don’t know the schemas in use I can only guess maybe mismatched datatypes on columns

Comment: disabling just my code should have given more insight as to where the exception is coming from do you have symbols loading enabled? so that it will download debug information from System.Data? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/specify-symbol-dot-pdb-and-source-files-in-the-visual-studio-debugger?view=vs-2022#configure-location-of-symbol-files-and-loading-options

Comment: Try `Merge` overload with `MissingSchemaAction` parameter specified.

Comment: @RandRandom I have enabled loading symbols, as well as "Show disassembly if source is not available". Debugger still points to line "inventTable.Merge(dt);"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [@AlexanderPetrov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5045688/alexander-petrov) I was able to fix this.
As he proposed, I added MissingSchemaAction parameter to my merge:

```
 inventTable.Merge(dt, false, MissingSchemaAction.Ignore);
```

after that it stopped giving me an error